# questions with Past Simple

Tags: questions, past-simple

If I ask a question in Past Simple using the coordinating conjunction *and*, does the second verb take -ed or not?

e.g. Did you muster up the courage and **propose**? or
     Did you muster up the courage and **proposed**?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the verb *-ed'* as you say. Why? Because when you have *Did...* it covers it!

> Did you muster up the courage and propose (to her/him)?*

The *and* joins the two actions and thus, they go in the same flow. Also, you are asking the person for the *past* action of having courage **and** proposing someone as well. So, no '-ed.'

Comment: I think you meant "propose _to_ her/him". I edited it in. Hope you don't mind.